# create a custom validation in laravel where input value must be greater than the existing value in the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a Printer model which has a page_count field..

the user will be able to input the current page_count...

the new page_count must be greater than the existing data in the database... How can I do that?

Comment: Get the data from db and use in Validator `'page_count' => 'required|min:'.$myValue) ... `. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Comment: thanks.. I'll temporarily use this.

Comment: I just changed customized the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue solved like this, though someone already gave the solution in the comments section.

```
/**
     * @param  array  $data
     * validates and Stores the application data
     *
     */
    public function sendMoney(Request $request)
    {
      //get the value to be validated against
        $balance = Auth::user()->balance;
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'send_to_address' => 'required',
            'amount_to_send' => 'required|max:'.$balance.'|min:0.01|numeric',
        ]);
     //some logic goes here
    }
```

Depending on your use case you could modify...

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `Printer` model which contains the `page_count` column.
You can define a custom validation rule in your `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot()` method.

```
public function boot()
    {
        //your other code

        Validator::extend('page_count', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
                    $page_count = Printer::find(1)->first()->value('page_count'); //replace this with your method of getting page count.
                    //If it depends on any extra parameter you can pass it as a parameter in the validation rule and extract it here using $parameter variable.
                    return $value >= $page_count;
                });

        //your other code
    }
```

Then, you can use it in your validation rule like below

```
'page_count' => 'required|page_count'
```

**Reference:** [Laravel Custom Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: If you get any issue, let me know